# Powershell script to run multiple input text files

Tags: powershell, text, spaces

I'm trying to remove spaces from input text file through PowerShell script.

I have hundreds if thousands of text files where I have to remove the spaces. I wrote the code to remove spaces. It is working fine for one text file but I want to execute more than one file .

```
gc C:\test\3.txt | where {$_ -ne ""} > C:\test\out.txt
```

In the above example I have more input files like 4.txt , 5.txt , 6.txt etc. I want to execute all the files in one shot and remove the spaces and write the 4out.txt, 5out.txt, 6out.txt, etc. to another folder.

Comment: Please stop using "lakh" in your questions. We're not all from India and don't understand Indian words

Answer (score 1):

It should just be a case of looping through your files and running the same line you already have.

Add some try-catch if you'd like to be safe.

```
$InputFiles = Get-ChildItem 'C:\test\'
$OutputPath = 'C:\test\out\'

ForEach($File in $InputFiles) {
    Get-Content $File |
        Where-Object {$_ -ne ''} |
            Out-File (Join-Path -Path $OutputPath -ChildPath $File.Name)
}
```